# Advance a UIScrollView with button

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

Hi I have a UiScroll view that contains an array of images and I can swipe back and forth to advance the loaded images.  However, I also would like to be able to control the scroll view advancing with a button action.  Here is the code for the scroll view:

```
int PageCount = 28;

        NSMutableArray *arrImageName =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"S2-4.png",@"D3-4.png",@"F2-4.png",@"B6-4.png",@"D6-4.png",@"S1-4.png",@"B7-4.png", @"D2-4.png",@"F7-4.png",@"B1-4.png",@"F3-4.png",@"D5-4.png",@"S3-4.png",@"B2-4.png",@"F5-4.png",@"D4-4.png",@"S7-4.png",@"F1-4.png",@"B3-4.png",@"S4-4.png",@"F6-4.png",@"D1-4.png",@"B4-4.png",@"S5-4.png",@"F4-4.png",@"D7-4.png",@"S6-4.png",@"B5-4.png",nil];

        scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
        scroller.scrollEnabled=YES;
        scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [scroller setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
        scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
        scroller.bounces = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:scroller];
        width=scroller.frame.size.width;
        xPos=0;
        for (int i=0; i<PageCount; i++)
        {
            UIImageView *ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height)];
            [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrImageName objectAtIndex:i]]];
            [scroller addSubview:ImgView];
            scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 0);
            width +=scroller.frame.size.width;
            xPos  +=scroller.frame.size.width;
        }
```

And then I have my button action but how would I perform the same advancing with the button?  Thank you.

```
- (void)nextPhoto: (id)sender {

}
```

I am relatively new to xcode and not sure how to manipulate the scroll view in this action.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at scrollRectToVisible:animated: - that will scroll things nicely to a specific place.